# Use union to defer member variable construction

Tags: c++, initialization, destructor, unions

I want to defer the construction of my member variable until the constructor's body and I am trying to use union to do that. Until now, it's achieving what I want but I want to ask is there any reason I shouldn't do this?

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A() {
    std::cout << "Construct A" << std::endl;
  }
  ~A() {
    std::cout << "Destruct A" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct B {
  A a;
};

template <typename T>
union U {
  char a{};
  T buffer;
  U() {}
  ~U() {
    buffer.~T();
  }
};

struct C {
  U<B> u;
  C() {
    try {
      new (&u.buffer) B();
    } catch (...) {
    }
  }
};
```

Edit: Add sample usage

Comment: The most immediate issue I see with this is that it's confusing. I think an array of `char`s that's the `sizeof` `A` would be the way to go, and then you use `operator new` in the constructor body of `B`. Does that achieve what you want as well? Also I'm sure your reasons for deferring construction until the body are valid, but would you mind sharing them for those of us in the back?

Comment: But then I can't use something like `u.b` for type safety

Comment: @JohnFilleau I added the sample for why I want to defer the construction. Basically I want to handle exceptions inside the constructor's body and not let them leak out to the outer scope.

Comment: The destructor of `U` shouldn't do anything. That makes it very easy to get UB, if you just end up not initializing `u.buffer` somehow before `u` gets destroyed. I'd feel better if the destruction of `u.buffer` were in `C::~C()`. E.g. if `B::B()` were to throw in this code as it is right now, I think there would UB. Otherwise, I think it's probably fine.

Comment: If the destructor of U doesn't do anything, the destructor of `B` and `A` will not be called. I don't see why if `B::B()` throws then it will be UB here, can you explain, please?

Comment: I think what you are doing is alright. It will seem a bit unaccustomed for most people and that is not the best thing but it is not a no-go either. Personally I think using std::optional or a factory method for the construction may be the better choice, but that would depend on your use-case. But I cannot think about a case where std::optional wouldn't be superior (even if it is a byte or so bigger).

Comment: @n314159 but because of alignment, it can range from 1 to 8 bytes, so potentially doubling the size. For example, `U<int64_t>` and `std::optional<int64_t>`.

Comment: @UyHà If `B::B()` throws, then `C::C()` will catch and ignore the exception. However, the `B` object `u.buffer` will not have started its lifetime, as it wasn't constructed. So far, that's fine. Now, eventually that `C` will be destroyed. After `C::~C()` is called, then `u.~U()` will be called (and there's nothing you can do to stop that!). `u.~U()` will try to call `u.buffer.~B()`, but there is no `buffer` to destroy. That's UB. A way around that would be for `U<B>::~U()` to do nothing and `C::~C()` to do `u.buffer.~B()` when needed. Utilities like `std::optional` encapsulate that logic.

Comment: @HTNW ok, I see. But if I rethrow the exceptions then it won't be UB anymore, right?

Comment: No, it will still be UB. Once the constructor body starts executing, all of the member variables have been initialized. If the constructor exits with an exception, those members will still be destroyed. This also calls `u.~U()` and then `u.buffer.~B()`, which will be UB if you didn't successfully initialize `u.buffer`. I think @yao99's answer is a good idea in that case: get rid of `U` entirely and just use a function-`try` to detect a failure in the member initializer. Basically, once you hit the `{` of `C::C()`, you *must* initialize `u.buffer` somehow to avoid UB, which may be difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the reason you should not use the work around is that it does not make sense.
Apply try-catch on hole constructor will work well.

```
struct C {
    A a;
    C() try {
    } catch (...) {
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't see how that can catch exceptions thrown by `A` but TIL `try` can be used like that.

Comment: The general syntax is actually like `C() try : a() { } catch(...) { }`. The construction of `a` happens under the `try` and is watched by the `catch`. This answer just leaves out the `: a()`, as it is implied. It still operates the same. [Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8Ka1Wb)

Comment: That's one example on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw.

Comment: Deferring construction of a member can indeed make sense; but for this specific purpose (handling an exception during construction) using your solution is far better. The union based solution provides more flexibility though (example: retrying construction of the member with different parameters)

Comment: @DanielJour Sure, that make sense. But it seems not the OP want to ask. Maybe the question should be edited.

Answer (score 1):

`std::optional` seems to be a great way to do this if you're at C++17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <stdexcept>

struct A {
    A(bool fail = false) {
        std::cout << "Attempting to construct A" << std::endl;
        if (fail) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to construct A");
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Succeeded in constructing A" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Destruct A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    std::optional<A> a;

    B(bool fail = false) {
        try {
            a.emplace(fail);
        }
        catch (std::runtime_error& ex) {
            // fall back to a safe construction
            std::cout << "Falling back to safe A construction" << std::endl;
            a.emplace();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        B b_good; // should be fine
    }

    {
        B B_bad(true); // should catch the exception and fall back
    }
}
```

output:

```
Attempting to construct A
Succeeded in constructing A
Destruct A
Attempting to construct A
Failed to construct A
```

---

An option that forgoes the size of `std::optional` is to have the unallocated buffer, but (for type safety) access it through a reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <stdexcept>

struct A {
    A(bool fail = false) {
        std::cout << "Attempting to construct A" << std::endl;
        if (fail) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to construct A");
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Succeeded in constructing A" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Destruct A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    char a_buff_[sizeof(A)];
    A& a_;

    B(bool fail = false) : a_(*reinterpret_cast<A*>(a_buff_)) {
        try {
            new (&a_) A(fail);
        }
        catch (std::runtime_error& ex) {
            std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Falling back to safe A construction" << std::endl;
            new (&a_) A();
        }
    }

    ~B() { a_.~A(); }

    B(const B& other) : a_(other.a_) {}

    B& operator=(const B& other) {
        a_ = other.a_;
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        B b_good; // should be fine
    }
    
    {
        B b_bad(true); // should catch the exception and fall back
    }
}
```

```
Attempting to construct A
Succeeded in constructing A
Destruct A
Attempting to construct A
Failed to construct A
Falling back to safe A construction
Attempting to construct A
Succeeded in constructing A
Destruct A
```

Comment: It doesn't achieve the same effect I want, I want exceptions to be caught inside the constructor's body and the size of the object to be as small as possible.

Comment: I tried another option that uses a buffer and reference. Although at this point I'm not sure if it's any less complicated than your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, it becomes too complicated too quickly.